# HP 6000 Pro SFF or holdout?

Tags: php

Perhaps not the right place for this question but I figure I might ask.

I am considering a purchase from a friend:

HP 6000 Pro Workstation Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7600 (3.06 GHz, 3 MB L2 cache, 1066 MHz FSB)
160gb hdd
4gb 1333 MHz DDR3

all for $350. While I think this is a pretty good deal I am unsure how the machine stacks up to other workstation caliber machines.

The majority of work I do is simple DB management, php, html and css writing and the occasional graphics work with adobe cs5.

Any advice? It this too antiquated to be good and should I get an i5 or i7 machine instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the design side, but seems like it will hold its own for the database and php coding. I am still on a single core for my coding machine, which runs LAMP to develop on. So I am sure it will work just fine for that.

Given it is a 3ghz Core 2 with 4GBs of ram (I take it is a 64 bit machine) it should handle adobe just fine as well.

**EDIT**

If you are planning on doing "extracurricular" work, such as gaming, I am not sure how it scales as I have been out of that business for some time.

Comment: no gaming at all - work only. I run single 2.8ghz 533 machine right now but want to upgrade simply for faster memory and hd (requiring new Mobo)